# Use delegate to write a method to take another method as an input parameter and the delegate should have unknown numbers of parameters

Tags: c#, delegates

Sorry that my title seems a little bit long and confused. Let me explain in details here. In my program, I have four methods. I just simplify their interfaces as

```
private static void methodA (Type1 Parameter1, Type2 Parameter2 )
private static void methodB (Type1 Parameter1, Type2 Parameter, Type3 Parameter3 )
private static Type4 methodC (Type1 Parameter1, Type2 Parameter2 )
private static Type4 methodD (Type1 Parameter1, Type2 Parameter, Type3 Parameter3 )
```

I'd like to write a generic retry logic for these methods (I do not want to add retry in each method). Do something like

```
for (int retry=0; retry<retrycount; ++retry)
{
    try {
        run the delegate function
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Thread.sleep (5000);
    }
}
```

What I am thinking is to write another method to use a function delegate as one input and the retry count as another input, something like. But these four methods signature are quite different. Some have outputs (C,D) and some do not (AB). Some have three input parameters (B,D) and some have two (A,C).

I just have a very simple c# book and its example of delegate are with the same signature. Not sure whether we can have a the delegate with different numbers of input parameters so at least we can combine method a, b and method c, d together.

if one delegate can have the option with have/have not output and we can combine a,b,c,d together and that will be much better.

Answer (score 1):

Here a couple of possible approaches to your problem. Both approaches allow your `delegate` method to accept a variable number of arguments.

If `Type1`, `Type2` and `Type3` have the same base type `BaseType`, you can define your `delegate` as follows:

```
delegate Type4 Method1(params BaseType[] parameters);
```

Alternatively, if your three input types do *not* have the same base type, you could supply three separate arguments, but default the third argument to `null`:

```
delegate Type4 Method2(Type1 param1, Type2 param2, Type3 param3=null);
```

In situations where you don't care about the return type `Type4`, simply return `null`.

Once you have defined your delegate, you could then use one of the following `Retry` methods:

```
void Retry1(Method1 method, int retryCount)
{
}

void Retry2(Method2 method, int retryCount)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with parameters, you can make your retry method take a parameterless delegate and then use a lambda when calling it. Something like:

```
void Retry(Action action)
{
    for (int retry = 0; retry < retrycount; retry++)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Thread.sleep (5000);
        }
    }
}

…

Retry(() => methodA(p1, p2));
```

For return value or no return value, you'll have to have two overloads of `Retry()`: one taking `Action` for `void` methods and the other generic one, taking `Func<T>` (and returning `T`) for functions that return a value.